# How to do a 'Button.Clicked' tag, but for Bunifu?

Tags: vb.net

I was wondering what the code is to if a button is selected, then say it will send the enter key. This make no sense, I know, and I'm sorry, but my code might help.

```
Private Sub BunifuCheckbox1_OnChange(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BunifuCheckbox1.OnChange
    If BunifuFlatButton1.clicked() And BunifuCheckbox1.Checked = True Then
        SendKeys.Send("{Enter}")
    End If
End Sub
```

So when you look at 'BunifuFlatButton1.clicked' is there a tag for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than try to send the string when you change the checkbox, delete that sub and use this. This way, you can change the checkbox and then click the button

```
Private Sub BunifuFlatButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BunifuFlatButton1.Click
    If BunifuCheckbox1.Checked = True Then
        SendKeys.Send("{Enter}")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The BunifuFlatButton1 somehow deleted in my project, so I renamed the new button to BunifuFlatButton1, but then it just gives this error: 'BunifuFlatButton1_Click' is already declared as 'Friend WithEvents BunifuFlatButton1_Click As BunifuFlatButton' in this class'. Thanks for understanding my question though.

Comment: Bizarre. there seems to be some underlying problem with your project - I would suggest creating a new project in a new instance of Visual studio and copying your code over. If possible, don't copy the controls, create new ones. I know this is a fair bit of work, but It will likely avoid more unusual problems. Otherwise, the code above should work. Deleting your project is really really wierd.

Comment: It's all good now, problem fixed without re-doing project. However, I've done everything you've said, but the code doesn't work. @David Wilson

Comment: What do you mean the code doesnt work? Is there an error?

Comment: No, there are no errors. But when I run the project, and I check the checkbox, it doesn't send the enter button key, instead, it just makes it normal so that the enter key doesn't get pressed.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "it just makes it normal" do you mean that the application you are sending to receives the string "{Enter}"? Try sending "{ENTER}" instead